# Custom UI Editor to create a button that calls macro from within Addin

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to have my Excel Addin add a custom button to the ribbon upon being enabled. The button should call the sub saved within the addin. I am using the Custom UI Editor and following the method outlined here http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm. It has worked to create the button but when I click the button it does not call the macro. It gives an error of "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment". The macro itself works correctly so I am assuming it is a problem with how I am writing the button. Any thoughts as to what I am doing wrong? The code below is what is in the UI Editor.

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
<ribbon>
 <tabs>

  <tab idMso="TabHome" >
    <group id="customGroup1" label="My Group" insertAfterMso="GroupEditingExcel">

      <button id="customButton1" label="Delete Totals" size="large" 
    onAction="DeleteBoldTotals" imageMso="HappyFace" />
    </group>
   </tab>

    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

The other variant I have tried, which makes it so the button doesn't even show up for some reason is;

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
<ribbon>
  <tabs>

  <tab idMso="TabHome" >
    <group id="customGroup1" label="My Group" insertAfterMso="GroupEditingExcel">

      <button id="customButton1" label="Delete Totals" size="large" 
    onAction=Application.Run "DeleteBoldTotals" imageMso="InkEraseMode" />
    </group>
  </tab>

  </tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

The macro I need it to call is:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteBoldTotals()
Dim vFIND As Range, vFIRST As Range, delRNG As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

 On Error Resume Next
 For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Set vFIND = ws.Cells.Find("Total", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not vFIND Is Nothing Then
        Set vFIRST = vFIND
        Do
        If vFIND.Font.Bold = True Then
            If delRNG Is Nothing Then Set delRNG = vFIND Else Set delRNG = Union(delRNG, vFIND)
        End If
        Set vFIND = ws.Cells.FindNext(vFIND)
    Loop Until vFIND.Address = vFIRST.Address
    If Not delRNG Is Nothing Then
        delRNG.EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
    End If
    Set vFIND = Nothing
    Set vFIRST = Nothing
    Set delRNG = Nothing
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Please share your macro, as its signature is important ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is correct. In the sub name you need to put:

```
Sub name(rib as iRibbonControl)
```

Comment: I am facing same problem ....where i need to add your code?

Comment: Once you have your xml saved for the CustomUI with the name of your sub, you just add the "rib as iRibbonControl" as the parameter for the sub.